# A class for rational number (p/q) with overloading + and << operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, friend-function

I wanted to add two rational numbers and display them in the form of p/q using overloading the operators + and <<.
I'm using friend function, because the function for addition and display are taking multiple and different types of parameters. Inside the addition function I'm performing a normal addition of fractions, like how we do in real life. But when i run the code i get an error that can't convert Rational to Rational(),
***Error:** `Rational.cpp: In function 'int main()': Rational.cpp:51:15: error: assignment of function 'Rational R3()' R3 = R1 + R2; Rational.cpp:51:15: error: cannot convert 'Rational' to 'Rational()' in assignment*`*

i have no idea why it's saying that .... ??

> C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rational
{
    private:
        int P;
        int Q;
    public:
        Rational(int p = 1, int q = 1)
        {
            P = p;
            Q = q;
        }
    
    friend Rational operator+(Rational r1, Rational r2);

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, Rational r3);
};

Rational operator+(Rational r1, Rational r2)
    {
        Rational temp;
        if(r1.Q == r2.Q)
        {
            temp.P = r1.P + r2.P;
            temp.Q = r1.Q;
        }
        else
        {
            temp.P = ((r1.P) * (r2.Q)) + ((r2.P) * (r1.Q));
            temp.Q = (r1.Q) * (r2.Q);
        }

        return temp;
    }

ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, Rational r3)
{
    out<<r3.P<<"/"<<r3.Q<<endl;
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    Rational R1(3,4);
    Rational R2(5,6);
    Rational R3();

    R3 = R1 + R2;
    cout<<R3;

}
```

Comment: `Rational R3();` -> `Rational R3;`. You declared a function taking no parameters and returning a `Rational`.

Comment: Is it necessary to create your own rational type? Can you use Boost? It has contained a [Rational](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/rational/) type for a long time.

Comment: classic C++ pitfall/typo :) https://godbolt.org/z/GsxbrKP4W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
Rational R3();
```

declares a function called `R3` that returns a `Rational` and takes no parameters. It does not define `R3` to be a default constructed `Rational`. Change the line to any of the below

```
 Rational R3; 
 Rational R3{};
 auto R3 = Rational();
 auto R3 = Rational{};
```

Comment: This is not the "most vexing parse". That refers to a [more subtle issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Which is not to say that it isn't vexing for beginners.

Comment: @PeteBecker I got vexed :P I knew there is a hole in my knowledge, just needed someone to put the finger on it. Cheers

Comment: @PeteBecker sometimes I need some embarassment in order to learn something =). I really though the term "most vexing parse" is more general  and what actually is the most vexing parse I thought was a special case of it. Thanks for the link, it helped to clear it up

Comment: Didn't mean to embarrass you. It's fairly common to see this referred to as the most vexing parse here on Stackoverflow; it's also fairly common for me to point out that that's not its original meaning. I am rather zealous about terminology; I worry, perhaps excessively, about having to backfill when terms of art lose their precise meanings. See any post that mentions "implicit cast". <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker oh sorry, I didnt take it as an offense. I appreciate it to get corrected especially when it is about using wrong terminology. Imho it is of major importance to use the terms correctly. It was a poor attempt to be joking, of course it shouldnt be embarssing to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There you go. Just remove the parenthesis from R3.

```
int main(){

    Rational R1(3,4);
    Rational R2(5,6);
    Rational R3;

    R3 = R1 + R2;
    cout<<R3;

}
```

Comment: You should explain **why** this answers the question and not just tell OP what to do. The problem is that OP may (if other, better answers didn't exist) not understand why exactly this fixes the problem.